# How do I choose 2 random elements from 2 lists and then.pop them so they won't be used again

Tags: python

```py
list1 = ["pineapple" , "apple" , "bananas" , "pear" , "pomegranate"]
list2 = ["strawberries" , "Grapefruit" , "guava" , "lemon" , "mango"]

accident = random.choice(list1)
accident1 = random.choice(list2)
```

here's the part when I need to pop it..or anywhere else really, I just need the two elements to be popped after they've been selected randomly

```py
print("Your cocktail is made from: ", accident, accident1)
```

Comment: Look at this: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove

Comment: You mention the word "pop." Why not use that?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Selection without repetition is well-documented on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.  Do the expected research and post your code if you have a problem.

Comment: If you're trying to randomise them before choosing again why not just shuffle the lists and iterate through the shuffled lists zipped together?

Comment: yea, it's for a school project, I'm really new to this and I want to use only things like pop because that's the things I know, I get that there's easier ways to do it with other commands but I'm trying to keep it simple..and not just copy it and not understand later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by pop like you mentioned. You can first do indexing and use `pop`.
Like this:

```
import random
list1 = ["pineapple" , "apple" , "bananas" , "pear" , "pomegranate"]
list2 = ["strawberries" , "Grapefruit" , "guava" , "lemon" , "mango"]

accident = random.choice(list1)
accident1 = random.choice(list2)
list1.pop(list1.index(accident))
list2.pop(list2.index(accident1))
print("Your cocktail is made from: ", accident, accident1)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Comment: thank you! exactly what I was looking for..appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `remove()` function to remove elements from a list:

```
In [60]: list1 = ["pineapple" , "apple" , "bananas" , "pear" , "pomegranate"] 
    ...:  
    ...: list2 = ["strawberries" , "Grapefruit" , "guava" , "lemon" , "mango"]                                                                                                    

In [61]:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [61]: import random                                                                                                                                                            

In [62]: acc = random.choice(list1)                                                                                                                                               

In [63]: acc1 = random.choice(list2)                                                                                                                                              

In [64]:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [64]: list1.remove(acc)                                                                                                                                                        

In [65]: list2.remove(acc1)                                                                                                                                                       

In [66]:                                                                                                                                                                          

In [66]: acc                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[66]: 'apple'

In [67]: acc1                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[67]: 'lemon'

In [68]: list1                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[68]: ['pineapple', 'bananas', 'pear', 'pomegranate']

In [69]: list2                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[69]: ['strawberries', 'Grapefruit', 'guava', 'mango']
```

Comment: It's better to use `randrange` and `pop` than `choice` and `remove`.

Comment: But really, it's usually better to shuffle the lists up front instead of trying to remove random elements from the middle.